# configure 4-way scroll

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, scrolling

My MS mouse has 4-way scrolling feature and OS understands it perfectly.

But, for some reason, I don't need its horizontal scrolling. Is it possible to reconfigure horizontal scrolling to act like vertical scrolling? I mean when I scroll to right, it goes up and when scroll to left, goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scroll wheel is seen as a pair of buttons, one for rotation in one direction and one for rotation in the other direction. Up is button 4, down is button 5, left is 6, right is 7. So remap the buttons so that physical button 7 is converted to logical button 4 and physical button 6 to logical button 5. You can do this with the [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html) command.

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 5 4'
```

If you're satisfied with the configuration, put the line `pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 5 4` in a file called `.Xmodmap` in your home directory. If that doesn't have any effect (it may depend on the Mint version), arrange to run the command above at login time.